# GoogleTV Builtin skin missing

Tags: google-tv

I developed an app on GoogleTV some time ago using API Level12 Emulater.

Just updated by ADT to ADT 21.0 and now if i try to create new AVD , I got following options

1. Device
2. Target
3. CPU
4. Skin with CheckBox

I can select target and choose the device and it works okay for mobile devices.

If I select
Target - GoogleTV Addon , In device section i don't get any compatible device and i can;
choose skin of 720p or 1080p. ( Previously option was there to choose skin for GoogleTV)

Please provide me, how i can define GoogleTv device with GoogleTV Addon as target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create a “Device Definition” and then use that for a new  “Android Virtual Device”. The device definition needs to have the right screen resolution and hardware specs configured: DPad, landscape orientation, large screen size and xhdpi density. I would recommend having both a 720p and a 1080p device configured for testing your layouts and bitmap resources.

Here is a link that has the steps to follow: http://waynemay.com/installing-and-configuring-the-google-tv-emulator/

Comment: Hi Leon , Nice Blog. One more query what about Linux. Previously we need to install KVM according to GoogleTV docs. But now KVM information is removed.Do we still need to install KVM in Linux.

Comment: Not sure if it is needed for Linux.